# NSNotificationCenter notifications not sent/received

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

// Question was answered, basicly  I should sleep more / code less :)

When my app starts i first load a splash screen, this splashscreen will start a dataDownload when the screen itself is done loading:

Splash.m

```
@implementation Splash


- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    _lblFunds = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 330, 324,28)];
    _lblFunds.numberOfLines = 1;
    [_lblFunds setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0]];
    [_lblFunds setTextAlignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [_lblFunds setText:@".. Fondsen .."];
    [self.view addSubview:_lblFunds];


    _lblObjects = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 360, 324,28)];
    _lblObjects.numberOfLines = 1;
    [_lblObjects setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0]];
    [_lblObjects setTextAlignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [_lblObjects setText:@".. Vastgoed Objecten .."];
    [self.view addSubview:_lblObjects];


    _lblCustomers = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 390, 324,28)];
    _lblCustomers.numberOfLines = 1;
    [_lblCustomers setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0]];
    [_lblCustomers setTextAlignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [_lblCustomers setText:@".. Clienten .."];
    [self.view addSubview:_lblCustomers];
    return self;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fundsLoaded) name:@"FundsDone" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(customersLoaded) name:@"CustomersDone" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objectsLoaded) name:@"ObjectsDone" object:nil];
}


- (void) fundsLoaded
{
    [_lblFunds setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fondsen geladen: %d",[[DataManager sharedInstance] fundsCount]]];
}

- (void) objectsLoaded
{
    [_lblObjects setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vastgoed Objecten geladen: %d",[[DataManager sharedInstance] objectsCount]]];
}

- (void) customersLoaded
{
    [_lblCustomers setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clienten geladen: %d",[[DataManager sharedInstance] customersCount]]];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[DataManager sharedInstance] getData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The DataManager will then proceed to use its instance of DataLoader to load and parse the data in a seperate thread, whenever data is parsed and stored away a Notification is sent from the DataLoader. If worked with the Notifications a lot before but this time it just will not work and I cannot seem to figure out why not. There is no error or anything, but the functions as set in the observers are never called. Any ideas on what is wrong are very much welcome, I have read quite a few threads on here, and other sites but haven't found my answer yet.

DataManager.m

```
@implementation DataManager

static DataManager* _dataManager = nil;
static DataLoader *_dataLoader = nil;
static bool _dataLoaded = FALSE;

- (int) fundsCount
{
    return _dataLoader.funds_count;
}

- (int) objectsCount
{
    return _dataLoader.objects_count;
}

- (int) customersCount
{
    return _dataLoader.customers_count;
}

+ (DataManager *) sharedInstance{
    @synchronized([DataManager class])
    {
        if(!_dataManager)
        {
            _dataManager = [[super alloc] init];

            _dataLoader = [[DataLoader alloc] init];
        }
        return _dataManager;

    }
    return nil;
}

- (void) loadDataSucces
{
    _dataLoaded = TRUE;
}


- (void) _getData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if(_dataLoader)
    {

        [_dataLoader loadData];

    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"DataLoader not initialized");
    }
    [pool drain];
}

- (void) getData
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(_getData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

@end
```

DataLoader.m

```
- (void) parseData: (NSString *) jsonString
{

    NSError *err;
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    id object = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:&err];
    [jsonString release];


    if (!object) {

    } else {

        //funds
        id funds = [object objectForKey:@"fondsen"];


        [self deleteAllEntitiesOfType:@"Fund"];

        int nr = 0;

        for (NSDictionary *i in funds)
        {
            NSString  *naam = [i objectForKey:@"naam"];

            if([naam length] > 2)
            {
                NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CatalogusAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];


                Fund *f = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Fund" inManagedObjectContext: context];
                NSString *integertje = [i objectForKey:@"oid"];
                int  in = [integertje integerValue];
                [f setOid: [NSNumber numberWithInt: in    ]];
                [f setNaam: naam];
                NSError *error = nil;
                if( ![context save: &error ])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[error userInfo] valueForKey:@"ErrorString"]);
                } else 
                {
                    nr++;
                }

            }

        }
        funds_count = nr;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FundsDone" object:nil];
        //objects



        if( true )
        {
            id objects = [object objectForKey:@"vastgoedobjecten"];


            [self deleteAllEntitiesOfType:@"Object"];

            nr = 0;
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CatalogusAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

            for (NSDictionary *i in objects)
            {



                Object *o = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext: context];

                [o setFondsOid:[NSNumber numberWithInt: [ [i objectForKey:@"fondsOid"] integerValue]  ]];
                [o setOid: [NSNumber numberWithInt: [ [i objectForKey:@"oid"] integerValue]  ]];
                [o setAdres:[i objectForKey:@"adres"]];
                [o setPostcode:[i objectForKey:@"postcode"]];
                [o setPlaats: [ i objectForKey:@"plaats"]];
                [o setProvincie:[i objectForKey:@"provincie"]];
                [o setStatus:[i objectForKey:@"status"]];
                [o setSegment:[i objectForKey:@"segment"]];
                [o setOppervlakte:[NSNumber numberWithInt: [ [i objectForKey:@"oppervlakte"] integerValue]  ]];
                [o setBelangrijksteHuurder:[i objectForKey:@"belangrijksteHuurder"]];
                [o setWeging:[i objectForKey:@"weging"]];
                [o setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [ [i objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]  ]];
                [o setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [ [i objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue]  ]];
                NSError *error = nil;
                if( ![context save: &error ])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[error userInfo] valueForKey:@"ErrorString"]);
                } else 
                {
                    nr++;
                }
            }

            objects_count = nr;
            NSLog(@"ObjectsLoaded");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ObjectsDone" object:nil];

        }

        //customers
        if( true )
        {
            id custs = [object objectForKey:@"klanten"];


            [self deleteAllEntitiesOfType:@"Customer"];

            nr = 0;
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CatalogusAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

            for (NSDictionary *i in custs)
            {



                Customer *c = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext: context];


                [c setOid: [NSNumber numberWithInt: [ [i objectForKey:@"oid"] integerValue]  ]];
                [c setFondsOid:[NSNumber numberWithInt: [ [i objectForKey:@"fondsOid"] integerValue]  ]];
                [c setNaam: [i objectForKey:@"naam"]];


                NSError *error = nil;
                if( ![context save: &error ])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[error userInfo] valueForKey:@"ErrorString"]);
                } else 
                {
                    nr++;
                }
            }

            customers_count = nr;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CustomersDone" object:nil];

        }

    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataReady" object:nil];

}

- (void) loadData{

    NSString *urlString = @"URL";

    NSDate *startDownload = [NSDate date];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;



    NSData *dataFeed = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
    if(error){

        NSString *d = [ error description ];
        NSLog(@"error: %@",d);
    }    int bytes = [dataFeed length];

    NSDate *endDownload = [NSDate date];



    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData decompress:dataFeed] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionExternalRepresentation];

    int string = [data length];

    NSDate *endDecompress = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"Download data: %f  - Decompress: %f  - BytesDownloaded: %d", [endDownload timeIntervalSinceDate:startDownload], [endDecompress timeIntervalSinceDate:endDownload], bytes);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadDone" object:nil];

    [self parseData:data];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In init, you should put your registration code BEFORE the return statement. Otherwise it will never run.

Cheers!

Comment: You just made me cry, smile, feel stupid and happy at the sametime *facepalm* thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! it happens to everybody :) Cheers.